# While loop with if statement is not working

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

I want the while loop to run as long as the name is not "1234". And if the name is only spaces, I want to print "name can not be only spaces" and ask for a name again. Else I want it to just ask for a name again.

```
name=input("")


while (name!="1234"):
  if(name.isspace):
    print ("name can not be only spaces")
    name=input("")
  else:
    name=input("")
```

The problem I have is that it prints "name can not only be spaces" for whatever string I give it. Even if the string does not have spaces it prints the if statement. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You might just be missing the parentheses of the `isspace` function.
So turn `isspace` into `isspace()` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As Mat has already mentioned, the problem you're facing is simply because name.ispace does not return a boolean like you need in your program.

[image]

Also, I think you could simplify your code a bit -

```
name=input("")


while (name!="1234"):
  if(name.isspace()):
    print ("name can not be only spaces")

  name=input("")
```